# Find the first img inside a div and place a new div below it

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to place a div below an image with jquery using the code below but it doesnt work.

in the `<head>` i have this code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img").prepend("<div id='1' style='width:400px; float: left; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
});
</script>
```

and inside the `<body>` i have this:

```
<div class="gdl-blog-full">
<img src="logoF.png" width="400" height="93" />
</div>
```

I just want to place a `<div>` below the image..

Answer (score 3):

like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/ymaaN/):

```
    $('.gdl-blog-full>img:first-child').after("<div>hello</div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [$.after](http://api.jquery.com/after/)

```
$('.gdl-blog-full').find('img:first-child').after('<div id='1' style='width:400px; float: left; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `.after` to put an element after a specified element, also `:first-child` to get the first image:

```
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img:first-child").after("<div id='1' style='width:400px; float: left; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
```

Answer (score 0):

not prepend it should be after

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$( document ).ready(function() {
$(".gdl-blog-full").find("img").after("<div id='1' style='width:400px; float: left; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>");
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use .insertAfter to put element after other.

```
$("<div id='1' style='width:400px; float: left; margin-top:10px; background-color: #000;'> You are watching 5th object out of 100 </div>").insertAfter(".gdl-blog-full img:first-child");
```